# MBA applicants age limits

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

Are you aware of any business schools that have age limits when considering MBA applicants? Schools that specifically state that candidates above, say, 35, need not apply?

Comment: Note: depending on the jurisdiction age discrimination could be illegal.

Comment: No, but at the age of 35, I'd assume the person in question is already likely employed and could potentially apply to an EMBA program instead, like [Wharton's Executive MBA](https://executivemba.wharton.upenn.edu/class-profile/) where the average age is mid-30s and a few dozen are above the age of 40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [Age discrimination is illegal](http://civilrights.findlaw.com/discrimination/age-discrimination-in-education.html) for all programs that receive public funding in the United States. Since a vast majority of schools receive funding of some sort from the US Dept. of Education, you wouldn't be discriminated against based on your age - unless you're applying to a school that doesn't receive public funding.